# R shiny: transforming reactive data.frame using reactiveValues and observe

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm having trouble transforming a reactive data.frame using reactiveValues and observe. I'm more familiar using the regular reactive() and can't quite grasp reactiveValues. I'd like to add a column called "Biomass" to the data.frame called tmp3. I'm able to transform tmp2 and add a column called "Class" and one called "Common" with no problem. A small snip of the server is below. If I try using transform to add the "Biomass" column the app wont run. I'm hoping someone could quickly glance at it and straighten me out. Let me know if providing the full code is necessary.

```
globals <- reactiveValues()

observe({

dat=read_lake_survey(SiteID())
surveys <- dat$result$surveys
tmp2 <- map2(surveys$fishCatchSummaries, surveys$surveyDate, ~{ 
.x$survey_date <- .y ; .x })
tmp2 <- map2(tmp2, surveys$surveyType, ~{ .x$survey_type <- .y ; .x })
tmp2 <- map2(tmp2, surveys$surveySubType, ~{ .x$survey_subtype <- .y ; .x })
tmp2 <- map2_df(tmp2, surveys$surveyID, ~{ .$survey_id <- .y ; .x })
tmp2[tmp2 == "N/A" ] <- NA 
tmp3=transform(tmp2,Class= abv$Coding[match(tmp2$species, abv$Abv)],
               FullName=abv$Common[match(tmp2$species, abv$Abv)])

  ### No luck adding this to the transform code  ######
  ### Biomass=tmp2$averageWeight*tmp2$totalCatch ###

  globals$ScrapedData=tmp3
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "app wont run"? What kind of error message do you get? I don't see any Shiny specific issues from this snippet.

Comment: The error is 'Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) :'. This happens when I try to add Biomass column using transform. `tmp3=transform(tmp2,Biomass=tmp2$averageWeight*tmp2$totalCatch,Class= abv$Coding[match(tmp2$species, abv$Abv)],
                   FullName=abv$Common[match(tmp2$species, abv$Abv)])`

Comment: Remove the zero-width non-joiner (`U+200C`) after the third `t` in `totalCatch`. I'm not familiar with this, just put it into a Unicode character identifier.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517463/scraping-html-data-table-using-rvest/46517874?noredirect=1#comment79990798_46517874] @greg L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the data.frame was a tibble.

```
tmp2 <- data.frame(type_convert(tmp2)
```

does not convert it to a data.frame. I needed to use 
    `class(as.data.frame(tmp2))` 
After properly converted, the transform function worked fine